# 'NULL' instead of 0 printed in txt file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, text

I have an input .txt file like this

```
head1      head2       head3      head3

0.004   5.104175   -1.651492   0.074480
0.015   5.104175   -1.327670   0.087433
0.025   5.104175   -1.181950   0.093910
...
```

and I want to subtract the first row to all the following rows in the same file, that is, printing a .txt file like this:

```
0       0           0          0 
0.011   0   -0.323825   -0.012953
...
```

here is my code:

```
for i = 1:length(x) %read all the files contained in folder_inp

    %%check file extensions
    [pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(x(i).name); 
    %%if it is a text file...
    if strcmp('.txt',ext)
        s = importdata(strcat(folder_inp,'\',x(i).name));
        init = s.data(1,:);
        for k=1:length(s.data)
            if s.data(k,:) == init
                s.data(k,:) = zeros(1,length(s.data(k,:)));
            else 
                s.data(k,:) = s.data(k,:)-init;
            end
        end

         fid = fopen( strcat(folder_out,'\',name,'.txt'), 'w' );
         formatSpecs = '%20s %20s %20s %20s \r';
        for j = 1:length(s.data)
            if j == 1
                fprintf(fid,formatSpecs,'head1','head2','head3','head4');
            elseif j==2 
                fprintf(fid,'\n') ;
            else 
                fprintf(fid,formatSpecs,s.data(j,1),s.data(j,2),s.data(j,3),s.data(j,4));
            end
        end

        fclose(fid);

     end

end
```

everithing works fine, exept the fact that instead of 0 the code prints a null character. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do the symbols a,b,c, etc. in your input file represent? I suppose you are actually subtracting numbers? Could you post a working example of the input file?

Comment: yes right. I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using the wrong [format specifiers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec) in your call to [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). You're using the conversion character `%s`, which will interpret your input arguments as character strings. Since your data is actually numeric, MATLAB attempts to first convert them to character strings. For floating-point values, this seems to work okay, but integer values get interpreted as ASCII codes and converted to their equivalent ASCII characters. Note this example, using `%s`:

```
>> sprintf('%s ', [pi 0 65 66 67 pi])

ans =

3.141593e+00  ABC 3.141593e+00
```

The values for [`pi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pi.html) are converted to an appropriate string, but `0 65 66 67` gets converted to a NULL character plus `ABC`.

You should instead be using format specifiers for numeric values, such as `%f`:

```
>> sprintf('%f ', [pi 0 65 66 67 pi])

ans =

3.141593 0.000000 65.000000 66.000000 67.000000 3.141593
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `%f` which will solve your problem, You can also do something like below to clean up the code and make it work for any number of columns and any header text.

```
% getting the headers
oldFile = fopen('text_in.txt');
headers = fgets(oldFile);
fclose(oldFile);

% reading and manipulating the data
data = dlmread('test.txt', '\t', 1, 0); % skip the first row of headers
data = repmat(data(1,:), size(data, 1), 1) - data; % subtract first row

% the format spec
formatspec = [repmat('%f ',1 , size(data, 2)) '\r\n'];

% writing to the new file
fid = fopen('text_out.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid,'%s',headers); % the header
fprintf(fid, formatspec, data'); % the data
fclose(fid);
```